# Python - reading/parsing binary file

Tags: python, struct, numpy, binaryfiles

I have .dat file that I m trying to read in python. File format is:

```
1.1 CDR description1 
Field   length(bytes)   Offset 
x   4            0
x1  2            4
x2  1            6
x3  1            7
......
......
......
x4  16          210 
x5  4           226 
x6  70          230
Total length of information     300
```

These are CDR records and I'm trying to read with the `struct` module but I can't understand how to use it with my specific file format... Any help?

Comment: What kind of information is stored in each field? You'll need that to figure out what struct module format codes to use.

Comment: Integers and letters, binary has 1000 of record of files and I m trying to print them all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know what *kind* of information is stored in each field for the `struct` module to make sense of each field.

For example, the first field at offset 0 is 4 bytes long, which means it could be an `int` (ranges from −2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647) or it could be a `unsigned int` instead (ranges from 0 to 4,294,967,295). It could also be a single-precision floating point number.

You probably also need to figure out the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your file format. If this is not explicitly named you need to experiment a little, or infer from context what it would be (a Windows file format is almost always little-endian, for example).

If you want to unpack the first 4 values only, you read the correct number of bytes (8 in your format) and pass this to the `struct.unpack` function together with a set of formatting characters to tell struct what types to expect. If we assume little-endian data, and the first four fields represent an unsigned int, an unsigned short and two unsigned chars, respectively, you'd use:

```
with open('something.cdr', 'rb') as data:
    x, x1, x2, x3 = struct.unpack('<IH2B', data.read(8))
```

Comment: Hmm, strage I have tried to print first 3 field using yours logic, but    x, x1, x2 = struct.unpack('<IH2B', data.read(7))
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 8

Comment: Make sure you understand the format; the `2` in front of the `B` means "expect 2 character bytes". If you want to parse just 3 fields, you need to adjust this to `'<IHB'` instead.

Comment: Is there any good turtorial on struck about formats, I m reading this one:http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html ? I m trying to get let say field 250, I know what I, H and B means, but I cant grasp what logic uses numer in front of B

Comment: That document is very complete; the only other useful link I could find for you is http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/struct/

Comment: Thank you for help, I think I understand now formats, but  now I have field with 14 bytes with offset 36 and I don't know how to print that with struck because format table doesn't have standard size more that 8

Comment: For example, I want to read field that has offset 210 and byte length is 16 bytes.  If it was 8 byte I would use:          struct.unpack_from('q', str(file.read()),offset=210), but how do I print 16 byte field?

Comment: @user1550881: what is contained in it? If it is character data, just read 1 character per byte; 16 bytes -> 16 characters.

Comment: Description of the field is: """Caller number, expressed with compressed BCD code, and the surplus bits are filled with “0xF”""". I have tried to print with format '16c' and I get: ('3', '\x00', '\x02', '\x05', '\x15', '\x13', 'G', 'O', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff', '\xff') and if I use '16b' I get (51, 0, 2, 5, 21, 19, 71, 79, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1).  And it is not correct, I should get phone number, and numbers above are invalid.

Comment: @user1550881: BCD stands for [Binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and you'll have to decode those manually. Those bytes stand for '330002051513474', if the padding is ignored and we read those digits in the same order as the byte stream. If you need help with decoding those, create a new Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thank you Martijn :) - your are BIG help, and just one thing confuses me, how do I tell python to read all CDR records if record is 907 bytes long. Is there something like "for record in file: do somethin with record" ?

Comment: @user1550881: each record has a fixed length right? So loop over the file until you can no longer read 907 bytes. Or use the `unpack_from` method to have `struct` read from the file directly, in a loop, and code to read 907 bytes every time.

Comment: Thx,  I will try and if I stuck I'l open new question. Bye